# how to filter object in different select box in angular2

Tags: angular

```
    batchObj:any= [
              {'batch':'28','term':'Term I','section':'Section I'},
              {'batch':'28','term':'Term I','section':'Section II'},
              {'batch':'28','term':'Term I','section':'Section III'},
              {'batch':'28','term':'Term II','section':'Section I'},
              {'batch':'29','term':'Term I','section':'Section I'},
              {'batch':'29','term':'Term I','section':'Section II'},
              {'batch':'30','term':'Term I','section':'Section I'},
              {'batch':'31','term':'Term I','section':'Section I'}   
              ];
```

html

```
    Batch : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_batch" > <option >Select Batch</option>
                       <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj;">{{item.batch}}</option>
                </select>
        Term : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_term"> <option>Select Term</option>
         <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj;">{{item.term}}</option>
         </select>           
        Section : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_section"> <option>Select Section</option> 
         <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj;">{{item.section}}</option>
        </select>
```

when page load `distinct batch` store in `sel_batch select box` then when select  `batch` then related `term` should show in `term select box` same work for in `section select box` when `term` select

how to do it in angular 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of angular2 pipes

now html will be

```
Batch : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_batch" > <option >Select Batch</option>
                       <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj| filterPipe;">{{item.batch}}</option>
                </select>
        Term : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_term"> <option>Select Term</option>
         <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj | filterPipe: ['batch', sel_batch, 'term'];">{{item.term}}</option>
         </select>           
        Section : <select  [(ngModel)]="sel_section"> <option>Select Section</option> 
         <option *ngFor="let item of batchObj | filterPipe: ['term', sel_term, 'section'];">{{item.section}}</option>
        </select>
```

and filterPipe.ts will be

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterPipe'
})

export class filterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform (value: Array<any>, args?: any) {
        let filterArray = [];
        let filterArray1 = [];
        if (args) {
            filterArray1 = value.filter(function(val, key) {
              if (val[args[0]] === args[1] && filterArray.indexOf(val[args[2]]) < 0) {
                filterArray.push(val[args[2]]);
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            });
        } else {
            filterArray1 = value.filter(function(val, key) {
            if (filterArray.indexOf(val.batch) < 0) {
                filterArray.push(val.batch);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            });
        } 
        return filterArray1;
    }
}
```

Include filterPipe in your declaration. Try this

Comment: showing error : zone.js:405 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filterPipe' could not be found

Comment: Did you include 'filterPipe' in your module ?

Comment: it work fine two condition required 1) distinct batch and when select term it should compare both batch and term when passing data to section now section showing all data

Comment: when select batch 29 it showing **Term I**  two times here distinct required

Comment: Apply some logic its simple

Comment: everything work great but still i could not fine how to distinct data because to shows duplicate contains which i donot want. I tried using different pipe but not suitable for one common logic for three select box

Comment: Edited answer plz check